# ¿Como se puede hacer multiples threads en Python?

Tags: python, hilos

me gustaria saber como se podria lograr hacer varios hilos que ejecuten varias funciones, por ejemplo, tengo un diccionario con funciones y un if que busca una funcion para ejecutar, pero si quiero que se ejecuten 2 funciones y que sean las mismas, ¿Como hago para que cada una se ejecute en un hilo por separado?

```
if parametro in funciones:
   funciones[command](message, parametro)
```

¿O existe una forma de que vaya igual de rapido en caso de que se ejecuten varias veces? Ando un poco perdido, porque tengo entendido que un hilo debe terminarse para luego empezar otro, y para hacer varios toca hacer muchas variables con hilos diferentes

Comment: Los hilos corren en paralelo, posiblemente en núcleos separados. Revisa https://docs.python.org/es/3.8/library/threading.html

Answer (score 0):

pues puedes usar **futures** es una libreria de python que permite hacer concurrencia,
El módulo concurrent.futures provee una interfaz de alto nivel para ejecutar invocables de forma asincrónica.

La ejecución asincrónica se puede realizar mediante hilos, usando ThreadPoolExecutor, o procesos independientes, mediante ProcessPoolExecutor. Ambos implementan la misma interfaz, que se encuentra definida por la clase abstracta Executor. ejemplo :

```
 from concurrent import futures
    executor = futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=25)
            x = []
            fin = ""
            for i in lista:
                #checkproxy es la funcion y i es el parametro que le paso a funcion
                x.append(executor.submit(check_proxy_ , i))
            for r in futures.as_completed(x):
                print(r.result())
                if r.result() != None:
                    fin += r.result() + "\n"
```

Comment: Aclara en cuales versiones de Python debes usar `import from future`. En la 3.8 basta con `import concurrent`

Comment: ¿Entonces si ejecuta muchas veces x funcion, en este caso check_proxy, se haran varios hilos? Gracias, Candid, por el link que me pasaste y a ti Cristian, por la explicacion

Comment: @HiroshiKumasuki aqui puedes leer acerca de threadpoolexecutor aqui en la documentacion te explican para que sirve cada parametro y si se haran 25 hilos pero no hay como tal un limite de subprocesos. [enlace](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/concurrent.futures.html)